# Highcharts Schedule for my Unit

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a schedule of events for my unit. Soldier_A might have 5 events, Soldier_B would have 7, etc. All this comes from a table in excel. I dump the data in the table to a cvs and pull from that. I see examples out there, and i cobbled the below code together. I am attempting to put all the dates into one line for that soldier.
   [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dassey/fzurG/2/)

Code:::::

```
$.get('data.csv', function (data) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');

    // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
    $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');

        // header line containes categories
        $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
            if (itemNo === 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
        });

        var series = {
            data: []
        };

        $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
            if (itemNo === 0) series.name = item;
        });

        $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
            if (itemNo > 0) series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
        });

        options.series.push(series);

    });

    // Create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

data.cvs

```
Soldier_A,2/28/2014,3/3/2014,1/10/2014,1/12/2014,4/4/2014,4/7/2014,1/24/2014,2/6/2014,2/8/2014,2/9/2014,3/7/2014,3/9/2014,6/18/2014,6/27/2014,5/2/2014,5/4/2014,6/21/2014,6/22/2014,7/9/2014,7/9/2014,7/12/2014,8/1/2014,8/2/2014,8/3/2014,9/6/2014,9/10/2014,9/20/2014,9/21/2014,11/1/2013,11/5/2013,11/7/2013,11/10/2013,12/7/2013,12/14/2013
Soldier_B,1/10/2014,1/12/2014,1/13/2014,1/17/2014,1/27/2014,1/31/2014,2/6/2014,2/9/2014,2/10/2014,2/14/2014,2/21/2014,2/23/2014,2/27/2014,3/2/2014,3/7/2014,3/9/2014,3/11/2014,3/11/2014,3/14/2014,3/16/2014,4/1/2014,4/6/2014,4/8/2014,4/8/2014,4/29/2014,5/4/2014,5/13/2014,5/13/2014,6/16/2014,6/22/2014,7/8/2014,7/8/2014,7/14/2014,7/21/2014,8/12/2014,8/12/2014,9/12/2014,9/12/2014,9/6/2014,9/7/2014,1/14/2013,1/14/2013,10/6/2013,10/6/2013,10/7/2013,10/7/2013,10/8/2013,10/8/2013,11/1/2013,11/6/2013,11/15/2013,11/17/2013,12/6/2013,12/8/2013,12/10/2013,12/10/2013
Soldier_C,10/9/2013,10/15/2013,10/22/2013,10/26/2013,11/3/2013,11/5/2013,11/13/2013,11/19/2013,12/6/2013,12/8/2013,12/15/2013,12/20/2013
Soldier_D,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/31/2013,11/6/2013
Soldier_E,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/24/2013,10/28/2013,10/31/2013,11/6/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,12/5/2013,12/9/2013
Soldier_F,10/6/2013,10/7/2013,10/8/2013,10/8/2013
Soldier_G,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/17/2013,10/21/2013,10/31/2013,11/6/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,12/9/2013,12/13/2013
Soldier_H,1/3/2013,1/6/2013,1/3/2013,1/6/2013,1/3/2013,1/6/2013,1/10/2013,1/13/2013,1/10/2013,1/13/2013,1/10/2013,1/13/2013,1/23/2013,1/27/2013,1/23/2013,1/27/2013,1/30/2013,2/2/2013,1/30/2013,2/2/2013,2/6/2013,2/9/2013,2/20/2013,2/24/2013,2/27/2013,3/3/2013,2/27/2013,3/3/2013,3/13/2013,3/17/2013,3/13/2013,3/17/2013,4/10/2013,4/14/2013,5/15/2013,5/19/2013,8/2/2013,8/22/2013,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/17/2013,10/20/2013,10/24/2013,10/28/2013,11/1/2013,11/4/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,11/22/2013,11/25/2013,12/5/2013,12/8/2013,12/5/2013,12/8/2013,12/5/2013,12/9/2013,12/5/2013,12/9/2013,12/10/2013,12/13/2013
Soldier_I,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/31/2013,11/4/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,12/5/2013,12/9/2013
Soldier_J,1/4/2013,1/5/2013,1/9/2013,1/13/2013,1/21/2013,1/21/2013,1/23/2013,1/23/2013,2/5/2013,2/10/2013,2/6/2013,2/10/2013,2/8/2013,2/9/2013,2/18/2013,2/18/2013,2/20/2013,2/20/2013,2/28/2013,3/2/2013,2/28/2013,3/2/2013,3/18/2013,3/18/2013,3/20/2013,3/20/2013,4/2/2013,4/6/2013,4/11/2013,4/13/2013,4/22/2013,4/22/2013,4/22/2013,4/28/2013,4/24/2013,4/24/2013,5/1/2013,5/5/2013,5/2/2013,5/4/2013,5/20/2013,5/20/2013,5/22/2013,5/22/2013,6/4/2014,6/13/2014,6/4/2014,6/13/2014,6/14/2014,6/19/2014,6/14/2014,6/19/2014,7/8/2013,7/14/2013,7/14/2013,7/19/2013,7/14/2013,7/21/2013,7/22/2013,7/22/2013,7/24/2013,7/24/2013,8/1/2013,8/10/2013,8/19/2013,8/19/2013,8/21/2013,8/21/2013,9/23/2013,9/23/2013,9/24/2013,9/24/2013,10/5/2013,10/6/2013,10/16/2013,10/21/2013,10/22/2013,10/22/2013,10/24/2013,10/24/2013,10/30/2013,11/4/2013,11/19/2013,11/19/2013,11/21/2013,11/21/2013,12/17/2013,12/17/2013,12/19/2013,12/19/2013
Soldier_K,1/14/2013,1/14/2013,1/10/2014,1/12/2014,1/13/2014,1/17/2014,1/27/2014,1/31/2014,2/6/2014,2/9/2014,2/10/2014,2/14/2014,2/21/2014,2/23/2014,2/27/2014,3/2/2014,3/7/2014,3/9/2014,3/11/2014,3/11/2014,3/14/2014,3/16/2014,4/1/2014,4/6/2014,4/8/2014,4/8/2014,4/29/2014,5/4/2014,5/13/2014,5/13/2014,6/16/2014,6/22/2014,7/8/2014,7/8/2014,7/14/2014,7/21/2014,8/12/2014,8/12/2014,9/12/2014,9/12/2014,9/6/2014,9/7/2014,11/2/2013,11/3/2013,11/4/2013,11/6/2013,12/6/2013,12/8/2013,12/10/2013,12/10/2013
Soldier_L,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/17/2013,10/21/2013,10/30/2013,11/4/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013
Soldier_M,7/14/2013,7/21/2013,1/3/2014,1/5/2014,1/10/2014,1/12/2014,2/7/2014,2/9/2014,3/6/2014,3/9/2014,4/3/2014,4/6/2014,4/11/2014,4/13/2014,5/9/2014,5/11/2014,6/7/2014,6/15/2014,10/4/2013,10/6/2013,10/4/2013,10/6/2013,10/18/2013,10/20/2013,11/1/2013,11/3/2013,11/14/2013,11/17/2013,12/6/2013,12/8/2013
Soldier_N,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/31/2013,11/7/2013,12/9/2013,12/13/2013
Soldier_O,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/17/2013,10/21/2013,10/31/2013,11/4/2013,11/21/2013,11/25/2013,12/5/2013,12/9/2013
Soldier_P,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/17/2013,10/21/2013,10/31/2013,11/4/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,12/5/2013,12/9/2013
Soldier_Q,7/14/2013,7/21/2013,10/3/2013,10/6/2013,1/3/2014,1/5/2014,1/10/2014,1/12/2014,2/7/2014,2/9/2014,3/6/2014,3/9/2014,4/3/2014,4/6/2014,4/11/2014,4/13/2014,5/9/2014,5/11/2014,6/7/2014,6/15/2014,10/4/2013,10/6/2013,10/18/2013,10/20/2013,11/1/2013,11/3/2013,11/14/2013,11/17/2013,12/6/2013,12/8/2013
Soldier_R,10/9/2013,10/14/2013,10/31/2013,11/6/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013
Soldier_S,1/4/2013,1/5/2013,1/6/2013,1/6/2013,1/15/2013,1/15/2013,1/17/2013,1/17/2013,1/23/2013,1/23/2013,1/27/2013,1/27/2013,2/3/2013,2/3/2013,2/7/2013,2/7/2013,2/10/2013,2/11/2013,2/18/2013,2/18/2013,2/26/2013,2/26/2013,3/4/2013,3/7/2013,3/8/2013,3/9/2013,3/11/2013,3/11/2013,3/18/2013,3/18/2013,3/26/2013,3/26/2013,4/12/2013,4/13/2013,4/22/2013,4/22/2013,5/3/2013,5/4/2013,5/20/2013,5/20/2013,7/4/2013,7/7/2013,7/8/2013,7/16/2013,9/6/2013,9/7/2013,10/2/2013,10/2/2013,10/4/2013,10/6/2013,6/7/2014,6/8/2014,10/10/2013,10/10/2013,10/14/2013,10/14/2013,10/16/2013,10/16/2013,10/17/2013,10/17/2013,10/28/2013,10/28/2013,6/9/2014,6/14/2014,6/18/2014,6/18/2014,8/5/2014,8/11/2014,11/2/2013,11/3/2013,11/4/2013,11/4/2013,11/12/2013,11/12/2013,11/14/2013,11/14/2013,11/14/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,11/18/2013,11/21/2013,11/21/2013,11/27/2013,11/27/2013,12/2/2013,12/2/2013,12/7/2013,12/8/2013,12/9/2013,12/9/2013,12/18/2013,12/18/2013
Soldier_T,10/7/2013,10/11/2013,10/14/2013,10/17/2013,10/20/2013,10/25/2013,3/7/2014,3/10/2014,1/10/2014,1/12/2014,1/24/2014,2/5/2014,2/6/2014,2/8/2014,5/2/2014,5/5/2014,3/17/2014,3/20/2014,4/3/2014,4/6/2014,6/21/2014,6/27/2014,6/21/2014,6/22/2014,7/9/2014,7/11/2014,7/12/2014,8/1/2014,8/2/2014,8/3/2014,9/20/2014,9/21/2014,9/6/2014,9/10/2014,11/1/2013,11/5/2013,11/18/2013,11/21/2013,12/6/2013,12/8/2013,12/8/2013,12/14/2013
Soldier_U,1/10/2013,1/13/2013,1/10/2013,1/13/2013,1/10/2013,1/13/2013,1/23/2013,1/27/2013,1/23/2013,1/27/2013,1/30/2013,2/2/2013,1/30/2013,2/2/2013,2/6/2013,2/9/2013,2/20/2013,2/24/2013,2/27/2013,3/3/2013,2/27/2013,3/3/2013,3/13/2013,3/17/2013,3/13/2013,3/17/2013,4/10/2013,4/14/2013,5/15/2013,5/19/2013,8/2/2013,8/22/2013,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/17/2013,10/20/2013,10/24/2013,10/28/2013,11/1/2013,11/4/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013,6/6/2014,6/8/2014,6/6/2014,6/8/2014,6/9/2014,6/28/2014,6/9/2014,6/28/2014,11/22/2013,11/25/2013,12/5/2013,12/8/2013,12/5/2013,12/8/2013,12/5/2013,12/9/2013,12/5/2013,12/9/2013,12/10/2013,12/13/2013
Soldier_V,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/31/2013,11/4/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013
Soldier_W,10/31/2013,11/5/2013,11/21/2013,11/25/2013
Soldier_X,10/3/2013,10/7/2013,10/31/2013,11/4/2013,11/14/2013,11/18/2013
Soldier_Y,1/4/2013,1/5/2013,1/9/2013,1/13/2013,1/21/2013,1/21/2013,1/23/2013,1/23/2013,2/5/2013,2/10/2013,2/6/2013,2/10/2013,2/8/2013,2/9/2013,2/18/2013,2/18/2013,2/20/2013,2/20/2013,2/28/2013,3/2/2013,2/28/2013,3/2/2013,3/18/2013,3/18/2013,3/20/2013,3/20/2013,4/2/2013,4/6/2013,4/11/2013,4/13/2013,4/22/2013,4/22/2013,4/22/2013,4/28/2013,4/24/2013,4/24/2013,5/1/2013,5/5/2013,5/2/2013,5/4/2013,5/20/2013,5/20/2013,5/22/2013,5/22/2013,7/8/2013,7/14/2013,7/14/2013,7/19/2013,7/14/2013,7/21/2013,7/22/2013,7/22/2013,7/24/2013,7/24/2013,8/1/2013,8/10/2013,8/19/2013,8/19/2013,8/21/2013,8/21/2013,9/23/2013,9/23/2013,9/24/2013,9/24/2013,10/5/2013,10/6/2013,10/16/2013,10/21/2013,10/22/2013,10/22/2013,10/24/2013,10/24/2013,10/30/2013,11/4/2013,11/19/2013,11/19/2013,11/21/2013,11/21/2013,6/4/2014,6/13/2014,6/4/2014,6/13/2014,6/14/2014,6/19/2014,6/14/2014,6/19/2014,12/17/2013,12/17/2013,12/19/2013,12/19/2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that first, you need to tell how this chart should look like. As I understand you need to have each soldier as one series (show up in legend). But what should be on xAxis, and what on yAxis? I guess you want for yAxis show that dates. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/fzurG/4/

Simplified code:

```
$.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
  var items = line.split(',');
  var series = {
      threshold: Date.UTC(2013,8,30), //use it to start from different value than year 1970
      data: []
  };
  $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
      if (itemNo === 0) {
          series.name = item;
      } else {
          series.data.push((new Date(item)).getTime());
      }
  });
  options.series.push(series);
```

Personally I would use scatter series for such chart: http://jsfiddle.net/fzurG/5/

Comment: The bottom axis would be dates (days), the side axis would be soldier names. Then in the chart would show all the dates for that soldier. Similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/dassey/M3DsP/

I have messed with that one to get data from cvs to populate instead of hard coded data. But no luck so far. Thanks for even looking at this!

Comment: Thanks for making in clear. However your data won't create such chart. You have for each soldier some date, while gantts chart required two dates for each (from-date and to-date) bar. I advice to use columnrange series in that case.

Comment: Thanks for that. How should I organize the data to make better sense? Each row has a soldier name and the dates. Each date is either a start date or end date. So if there are 4 dates on that row, it is two events. I can certainly organize the data anyway needed. Thanks for your help as well, really appreciated.

Comment: If you have always even number of dates for soldier, and you now that first is start date, then second is end date, you can simply preprocess data in that way, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/fzurG/11/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dassey/aupb2/1/ Mine doesnt look similar to yours..But I am using similar data? Is there a limit to how many I can have? Anyway, you have gotten me closer than anyone else and I really do appreciate it.

Comment: I want to have your children now. You sir, are a god amongst men.

Answer (score 0):

First you can parse each of the dates into a timestamp doing the following:

`var ts = (new Date(item)).getTime();`

That gets you the javascript timestamp which Highcharts works with.

Next you'll probably want to disable the tick interval part since that often goes wrong on datetime graphs.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example on how to use that?